# SQL - Should I add an IF or CASE to this WHERE clause?

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, case

I've written a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT
xx.DATE
xx.TRANSACTION_ID
xx.ID
xx.CODE

FROM TABLE_X xx

WHERE
xx.DATE >= TO_DATE('2015-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
AND xx.ID IN 
(SELECT
yy.id
FROM TABLE_Y yy
WHERE
yy.status = 'OPEN'
AND yy.type = 1
AND trunc(yy.date) = TO_DATE('{FREE_FORM}', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
)
```

ex.TABLE_X

```
DATE        TRANSACTION_ID  ID      CODE
1/1/2015    1020            CAT     RED
1/1/2015    1010            CAT     GREEN
1/2/2015    2020            DOG     RED
1/2/2015    2010            DOG     GREEN
1/3/2015    3030            RABBIT  BLUE
1/3/2015    3020            SPIDER  RED
1/3/2015    3010            RABBIT  GREEN
1/4/2015    4020            CAT     RED
1/4/2015    4010            SNAKE   GREEN
1/4/2015    4000            MONKEY  ORANGE
1/5/2015    5020            HORSE   RED
1/5/2015    5010            COW     GREEN
```

ex.TABLE_Y

```
date        id      status  type
1/1/2015    CAT     OPEN    1
1/2/2015    DOG     OPEN    1
1/3/2015    RABBIT  OPEN    1
```

With these example tables my current output is:

ex.output

```
DATE        TRANSACTION_ID  ID      CODE
1/1/2015    1020            CAT     RED
1/1/2015    1010            CAT     GREEN
1/2/2015    2020            DOG     RED
1/2/2015    2010            DOG     GREEN
1/3/2015    3030            RABBIT  BLUE
1/3/2015    3010            RABBIT  GREEN
1/4/2015    4020            CAT     RED
```

I'd like to add something to maybe the WHERE clause like:

```
if (ex.output.CODE = RED){
SELECT
xx.DATE
xx.TRANSACTION_ID
xx.ID
xx.CODE

FROM TABLE_X xx

WHERE xx.TRANSACTION_ID = ex.output.TRANSACTION_ID - 10
}
AND
if (ex.output.CODE = GREEN){
SELECT
xx.DATE
xx.TRANSACTION_ID
xx.ID
xx.CODE

FROM TABLE_X xx

WHERE xx.TRANSACTION_ID = ex.output.TRANSACTION_ID + 10
}
```

My goal is to end up with an output of:

```
DATE        TRANSACTION_ID  ID      CODE
1/1/2015    1020            CAT     RED
1/1/2015    1010            CAT     GREEN
1/2/2015    2020            DOG     RED
1/2/2015    2010            DOG     GREEN
1/3/2015    3030            RABBIT  BLUE
1/3/2015    3020            SPIDER  RED
1/3/2015    3010            RABBIT  GREEN
1/4/2015    4020            CAT     RED
1/4/2015    4010            SNAKE   GREEN
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Why don't you put the condition in `where clause`, and then `union` both result?

Comment: please state the conditions clearly

Comment: The answer is no. Use `AND`/`OR` instead in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query (written in MS T-SQL)

```
WITH    CTE
          AS ( SELECT   xx.DATE ,
                        xx.TRANSACTION_ID ,
                        xx.ID ,
                        xx.CODE
               FROM     TABLE_X xx
               WHERE    xx.DATE >= '2015-01-01'
                        AND xx.ID IN ( SELECT   yy.id
                                       FROM     TABLE_Y yy
                                       WHERE    yy.status = 'OPEN'
                                                AND yy.type = 1 )
             )
    SELECT  *
    FROM    CTE
    UNION
    SELECT  xx.*
    FROM    TABLE_X xx
            JOIN CTE ON xx.Transaction_ID = CTE.Transaction_ID - 10
                        AND CTE.Code = 'RED'
    UNION
    SELECT  xx.*
    FROM    TABLE_X xx
            JOIN CTE ON xx.Transaction_ID = CTE.Transaction_ID + 10
                        AND CTE.Code = 'GREEN'
    ORDER BY Date ,
            ID;
```

The above query will provide an output of

[image]

Comment: Question is tagged `mySQL` and not `sql-server` e.g. mySQL does not support CTEs.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your request correct then the last line for the `ID='CAT'`  (`1/4/2015,4020,CAT,RED`) should not be in your final output. You do not get a calculated `TRANSACTION_ID` of 4020 anywhere in **ex.output**.

I would build the query like this:

```
SELECT 
xx.DATE,
xx.TRANSACTION_ID,
xx.ID,
xx.CODE 
FROM TABLE_X xx
WHERE TRANSACTION_ID IN 
(SELECT CASE eo.CODE WHEN 'RED' THEN TRANSACTION_ID-10 WHEN 'GREEN' THEN  TRANSACTION_ID+10 ELSE TRANSACTION_ID END  as trx_id
 FROM ex.output eo)
```